# Having an issue while connecting to DataGrid View

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid

I have previously used the same code to connect to different dataGrid views but for my Inventory Table, I'm unable to connect to the dataGrid. on Executing the code, at runtime, the datagrid is blank.

```vb
        Try

            Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MAYUR\Desktop\TechUp\Srinath\SrinathDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
            connection.Open()
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Inventory", connection)
            Dim dataset As New DataSet()
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "Inventory")
            dgInventory.DataSource = dataset.Tables("Inventory")
            dgInventory.Refresh()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed to connect to database. " & ex.Message, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Connect to DB Error!")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
```

Comment: Add a line directly after `adapter.Fill(dataset, "Inventory")`  `Debug.Print(dataset.Tables("Inventory").Rows.Count.ToString)`  to see if you have returned any rows.

Comment: Yes, it does return rows but does not display it in the datagrid, moreover, it should atleast show the table definition even if it does not return rows.

Comment: Is this changing the display in the grid or is this the first thing display? Is there anything added to the grid at design time? Are there any properties set other than the defaults and location and size?

Comment: I don't think you should need the .Refresh but you have probably already tried it with and without.

Comment: This is WinForms. Yes?